# How to take Fourier transforms wrt arbitrary variables?

Tags: matlab, fft, dct, cartesian-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

I want to take FFT of following forms:
[Fourier in spherical coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zlx1.png)

So in fact, my `f(theta,phi)` is a 3D image voxel, ie it has f(radius,theta,phi). If I had to take integral along dx, that would amount to just selecting my IMG(ylocation,:,zlocation)=currentvoxel and running fft(currentvoxel) on it. However, now I have to only take fft along phi. Which is hard because it requires for me to find all the locations with theta=currenttheta and for each r=currentr, I have to find all the phi's to take fft.

I don't even know how to unroll the phi to take fft. When it's Cartesian coordinates, it's easy, just start from x=0,..x=end and run fft. Is phi case the same? Get all the phi's on a certain r,theta and **sort them 0 to 2pi** and take fft?

Or maybe sine/cosine transforms like this:
[cosine/sine transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwiER.png)

If this was a f(x,y), I think the way to do this in MATLAB would be to take dct(f*(x.^2+y.^2)). In other words running a discrete cosine transform. Am I right?

Extra clarification on second part:
The integral I'm interested in is: [bessel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbj0o.png)
where j_l(kr): [expanded j_l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4pKA.png)
and
[expanded further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wI3V.png)
finally the F_(l)(t) is given by previous: [cosine/sine transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwiER.png)

Comment: cosine \ sine transforms are for semi-infinite boundaries. The proper way for a radial FT (that has a Jacobian rdr) is the [Hankel transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelTransform.html). However, I didn't understand if that's enough or are you actually transforming also the angle? can you please write down the integral you want to solve?

Comment: @bla I updated my question (last part) to include more information , can you check?

Comment: can you please have one, concise, minimal example that is given in complete form  that will answer your question? your exta clarification is far from  clear.

Comment: @bla My f(r) is not dependent on angles. It is but for the purposes of the wuestion you can think it’s a fn only dependent on r. Then i try to get the result of the cosine/sine fourier.